# How to get the passenger_app_env value from shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am currently working on a shell script to manage a service who is part of a `Rails` App (Nginx + Phusion Passenger) and needs to be launched with `systemd` after Rails has started.

As a requirement the script needs the Rails environment value and I would like to get it from Passenger (`passenger_app_env` value).

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf:
server {
    ...
    # Ensures that RAILS_ENV, NODE_ENV, etc are set to "staging"
    # when your application is started.
    passenger_app_env staging;
}
```

I was trying with `passenger-config about OPTION`, `env`, and `printenv` to get that value but without luck.

Does anybody know a way to get the value of `passenger_app_env` from the OS shell?

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking. If you are looking to get the env var in Ruby you can get it through `ENV['passenger_app_env']` otherwise it depends on whatever this mysterious script is written in.

Comment: Hey max, I want to get that value using a shell script, not Ruby but I cant find the way to do it. I did update my question.

Comment: According to the passenger reference docs, [passenger_app_env](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_app_env) sets several environment variables for a given application, so what don't you write a simple rake taks that will return `PASSENGER_APP_ENV`?

Comment: I just want to know how to get the env variables of the passenger ruby proccess from the shell. Anyway, it is not possible to get environment vars between ruby procceses, so the rake task should be a child proccess of passenger to access to their variables.